# Extract numbers from string in R

Tags: r, string

I have a string variable in an R data frame containing different numbers separated by |. Typical values of this variable are of different length, and look like this:

```
st <– c("7.4|7.4|8|8|8|8|7.4|7.4|7.4|","0|-32|0|0|-32|-3|-3|-3|-3|-3|-3|-3|")
```

I would like to count the occurrence of each number. The different numbers actually correspond to variables in my data frame:

```
 v1 <- c(8,-32) 
 v2 <- c(0,0)   
 v3 <– c(7.4,-3)
```

So ideally, I would just count the number of instances equal to each of the variables, and get something like this:

```
count_v1 = c(4,2)
count_v2 = c(0,3)
count_v3 = c(5,7)
```

Any idea how I could do this?

Here is a minimal example:

```
st <- c("7.4|7.4|8|8|8|8|7.4|7.4|7.4|","0|-32|0|0|-32|-3|-3|-3|-3|-3|-3|-3|")
v1 <- c(8,-32) 
v2 <- c(0,0)   
v3 <- c(7.4,-3)

dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(v1,v2,v3,st))
```

Again, I would like to have new variables with the counts of  added to the same data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(st, "|", fixed = TRUE), seq_along(st)))[2:1])
   values
ind -3 -32 0 7.4 8
  1  0   0 0   5 4
  2  7   2 3   0 0
```

Now you could read off the values you want from this table

## EDIT:

```
st <- c("7.4|7.4|8|8|8|8|7.4|7.4|7.4|","0|-32|0|0|-32|-3|-3|-3|-3|-3|-3|-3|")

tab <- table(stack(setNames(strsplit(st, "|", fixed = TRUE), seq_along(st))))

v1 <- c(8,-32) 
v2 <- c(0,0)   
v3 <- c(7.4,-3)


v <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
ind <- cbind(as.character(c(t(v))), as.character(t(row(v))))

cbind(v, count = matrix(tab[ind], nrow(v), byrow = T))



   v1 v2   v3 count.1 count.2 count.3
1   8  0  7.4       4       0       5
2 -32  0 -3.0       2       3       7
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! Any ideas how I could turn the tabulated values into variables in my dataframe by matching them with columns v1, v2, and v3?

Comment: @Max Montana you have very many variables lying around. please create a dataframe that you want and i will help you transform this result into your dataframe. eg do you have `data.frame(v1, v2, v3)`?

Comment: thank you for your help with this. I have now edited my original post to reflect that the variables pertain to one data frame. Can the counts be added to such a data frame?

Comment: @MaxMontana i already edited the solution and gave you the answer. Check the edited part

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I missed this. Thank you so much, Onyambu, it works like a charm!